# array length...different outputs when using sizeof operator

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

so i was just playing around with the code to find array length....
the orignal code was:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{   int al;
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    al= sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    printf("%d",al);
    return 0;
}
```

which gave me the output of:

> 5

but when i changed the expression to:

```
al= sizeof(&a[0]) / sizeof(a[0]);
```

it gave me the output of

> 2

if `a` is the same as `&a[0]` ...then why does this happen?
Also, if put `&a` in place of `&a[0]` the answer is also  2.

Comment: `if "a" is the same as "&a[0]" ...then why does this happen?` Because `a` is _not_ the same as `&a[0]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, they differ in type.

For context of `sizeof` operator, `a` is of type `int [5]`, but , `&a[0]` is of type `int *`. They are indeed of different size. Following the same analogy, `&a` is of type `int (*)[5]` - basically, a pointer.

So, for the expression

```
al= sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
```

is the same as

```
al= sizeof( int [5]) / sizeof(int);
```

which gives you 5. On the other hand,

```
al= sizeof(&a[0]) / sizeof(a[0]);
```

is the same as

```
al= sizeof(int *) / sizeof(int);
```

now, it appears, in your platform, `sizeof(int *)` is 8 and `sizeof(int)` is 4, so you get to see a result of 2.

Remember, in some cases, array type decays to a pointer to the first element of the array, but one of the exceptional cases where is does not, is when the array is used as the operand of `sizeof` operator.

Comment: can you explain in a bit more detail please? dumb it down for me...i am new to programming

Comment: @SouravGhosh  just saw it

Comment: @AnasAziz `sizeof()` is not a function, it's preprocessed at compile time. At some point all arrays are handled as pointers, and they implicitly convert into pointers aswell, but only at compile time the compiler knows that is an array and what is it's real size. `sizeof()` cannot tell the size of an array just from it's pointer, and that's why it will give you the size of the pointer instead (8, for 64-bit pointers).

Comment: @Havenard `sizeof` is not part of what is usually called "the preprocessor"; you can't use it in preprocessor arithmetic. Also it is not true that "At some point all arrays are handled as pointers",  that sort of bogus statement is what leads to beginners being confused about this issue in the first place

Comment: @M.M Please clarify why it's bogus. Also I never said the preprocessor was responsible for preprocessing `sizeof()`, I simply used the *to preprocess* verb for lack of a better one and explicitly attributed the action to the compiler.

Comment: @Havenard Arrays and pointers are different, it's bogus to say that arrays are "handled as pointers" (whatever that even means). Pointers can point to elements of an array but there is no equivalency other than in syntax.